# Can Pass by Value Affect the Asymptotic Time Complexity of A Recursive Algorithm?

Tags: c++

In the following program, a helper function is called recursively in order to create a Binary Tree from the preorder and postorder traversals which are represented by an array. The runtime is fast and beats a 100% of all submissions on Leetcode.

```
TreeNode* buildTree(vector<int>& preorder, vector<int>& inorder) {
    unordered_map<int,int> m;
    for(int i=0; i<inorder.size();i++){
        m[inorder[i]]=i;    
    }
    return helper(preorder, inorder, 0,preorder.size()-1,0, inorder.size()-1, m);
}

TreeNode* helper(vector<int>& preorder, vector<int>& inorder, int pStart, int pEnd, int inStart, int inEnd,unordered_map<int,int>& m){
    if(pStart>pEnd || inStart>inEnd) return NULL;

    TreeNode* root= new TreeNode(preorder[pStart]);
    int pivLoc=m[root->val];
    int numsLeft=pivLoc-inStart;
    root->left=helper(preorder, inorder, pStart+1, pStart+numsLeft,inStart, pivLoc-1,m);
    root->right=helper(preorder, inorder, pStart+numsLeft+1, pEnd,pivLoc+1, inEnd,m);
    return root;
}
```

However, if I change the helper function such that the last parameter (the unordered_map) is passed by value, it gets a runtime exceeded error. I am trying to understand why. The map's itself is never reassigned, nor are its values. Since the map is being passed by value, that would mean the copy constructor is called each time the function is called. Is that going to increase the functions runtime by a constant factor or will it actually change the asymptotic complexity? I believe the copy constructor is causing a large increase but only by a constant factor, since a copy is a constant time operation in relation to the input.

Comment: I am aware of the cost associated with calling the copy constructor each time the parameter is passed. I am trying to understand whether that cost is a constant factor or not.

Comment: This may or may change the complexity, depending on how many times `helper` is called. The copy is an O(n) operation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes.

If the size (or number of elements) of a parameter that gets copied is a function of `N` (and not a constant,) then it will have an effect on the asymptotic time of your implementation (even if it's not recursive.) For example, if you copy an array of size `O(N)` even only once, then you should consider that in your asymptotic analysis (it might not have an effect if your order is already `O(N)` or higher, but you have to count it in nonetheless.)

In a recursive implementation, obviously you'll have something like `O(f(N))` function calls (`O(log(N))` for searches, `O(N)` for sorts, etc.) and the cost of copy will affect or even dominate your time. Obviously, the cost of passing a parameter of size `M` to a function that is called `N` times is `O(N * M)`. If the size changes with each invocation, you can still calculate the sum (using standard techniques.)

Even if the size of the parameter in question is constant and small (but not negligible,) if the function is called `O(f(N))` times, then you have to add `f(N)` to your asymptotic time analysis.

The cost of copy itself depends on many things, but for a container of `N` elements (unless it has some reference-counting/COW optimization or the like) I daresay that the cost of copy is `O(N)`. For containers that keep their elements in one (or a few) contiguous block(s) of memory, the constant factor on the copy operation will mostly depend on the cost of copy for individual elements, as the overhead from the container and memory management is small. For linked-list style containers (which include `std::map` and `std::set`) unless you have custom memory allocators and very specific strategies, the cost of memory allocation and traversal will be significant (depends very much on the total number of elements and heap pressure and your OS/standard library implementation, etc.)

Depending on the type of your elements in the containers, in addition to the cost of copy, you might have to consider the cost of destruction as well.

**Update**: After seeing more of your code (still not a working example though, but probably enough) I can give you a more detailed analysis. (Assuming that the size of your input is `N`,)

The function `buildTree` has two main parts: the loop and the recursive call to `helper`. The "loop" part has a complexity of `O(N * log(N))` (the loop repeats `N` times, and each time inserting into a `std::map` which is logarithmic in the size of the map, hence `O(N * log(N))`.

To work out the cost of calling `helper`, we need to know how many times it is called, and how expensive its body is, and how much its input shrinks in each recursive call. Obviously, the `helper` function is called `2 * N + 1` times in total (twice per input element, and once in `buildTree`) which is obviously `O(N)`, and its input never changes size (it does, but no part of its body is dependent on the input size except the termination condition.)

Anyway, the interesting operations inside `helper`'s body are the `new` (usually considered `O(1)` which is a little simplistic but acceptable here,) the lookup in the `std::map` (which is `O(log(N))`,) and the calls to `helper`. The cost of those calls are `O(N)` if we copy any of the `vector` or `map` parameters (again, assuming memory allocation and copying of each element are `O(1)`,) and `O(1)` if we don't.

So, the total time is time of the loop plus time of the call to `helper`, and time of the call is the number of calls times the time per call. The time of the loop is `O(N * log(N))` and the number of calls is `O(N)`.

The time for each invocation of `helper` is the time of allocating a new node (`O(1)`) plus looking up the value in our map (`O(log(N))`) plus twice the time of invoking `helper` again.

If we pass the parameters by value (i.e. any of `inorder`, `preorder`, or `m` is passed by value) then the time of each invocation of `helper` will be `O(N)`, and if we pass all parameters by reference, then that time will be `O(1)`. So, putting it all together, if we pass our large parameters by value, we get:

```
  O(N * log(N)) + O(N) * [O(1) + O(log(N)) + O(N)]
= O(N * log(N)) + O(N) * O(N)
= O(N * log(N)) + O(N^2)
= O(N^2)
```

and if we only pass by reference we'll have:

```
  O(N * log(N)) + O(N) * [O(1) + O(log(N)) + O(1)]
= O(N * log(N)) + O(N) * O(log(N))
= O(N * log(N)) + O(N * log(N))
= O(N * log(N))
```

and that's it.

(As a side note, if the parameter to a function is not going to be changed, and is only passed by reference to avoid a copy, then it is passed as a *constant reference* or `const &`.)

Comment: @user3586940, that makes the size of the map be `O(N)`, would it not? And I don't remember the algorithm you are implementing, but I guess it's `O(N)` itself, meaning that it will call this helper function about once for each element in the tree, which makes the cost of passing that map around be `O(N^2)` in and of itself. If my assumption is wrong, you can post more of your code so we have more information to go on.

Comment: I posted the entire program. The map that is passed by value/reference is never altered in any way and is the same size as the original input arrays. I'm not sure if that changes things.

Comment: I wish I could upvote this answer 5 times. I get it now. Thanks.